# autocomplete mixed with keydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I do an autocomplete with jQuery/Ajax and I want to bind to events,when I fill the input to get some displayed values(autocomplete) or when I hit the submit button as well:

```
$('input[type='text']').on('keydown',function() { 

    displayFunction();

});

OR 

$('input[type='submit']').on('click',function() { 

   displayFunction();

});
```

I want to have something which can mix the 2 events:

```
$('').on('keydown click',function() {//Here in the 2 differents input...
      displayFunction();
});
```

Thanks for your help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separe both selector with `,`:

```
$("input[type='text'], input[type='submit']").on('keydown click',function() {//Here in the 2 differents input...
      displayFunction();
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cN98M/)